# Non-breaking space in Flutter arb file

Tags: flutter, unicode, localization, arb

I am trying to add the non-breaking space in my `arb` file in Flutter app, however, I can't find any way to put the Unicode characters to the `arb` file.

I need something like:

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "helloWorld": "Hello&nbsp;world!",
}
```

Is it possible to add custom characters other than `\n` etc to `arb` files?

Comment: "Hello world!" wont work?

Comment: Is "Hello\u{00A0}world!" any good?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( arb files dont support that format :(

Comment: Doesn’t it even work copying and pasting the [Unicode character](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `\u00A0` in arb:

```json
  "forceUpgradeButtonText": "Hello\u00A0world",
```

Then in Dart app_localizations_en.dart:

```dart
  @override
  String get forceUpgradeButtonText => 'Hello world';
```

the character between is `NO-BREAK SPACE` according to [this page](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=Hello%C2%A0world)

Comment: "countries": "{choice, select, United States {United States} United Kingdom {United Kingdom} other {None}}", 

How to solve the spacing issue in the option United States or United Kingdom??